# How to select a value from a DropdownButton using Flutter Driver?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'd like to select an entry from a DropdownButton in a form. I managed to tap on the button using the following:

```
await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('object_type'));
```

How can I find an entry now? The DropdownMenuItem entries are dynamically generated using values from a database. I think it's kind of awkward setting a key for each value, so I tried the following:

```
await driver.tap(find.byValueKey('object_type'));
await driver.waitFor(find.text('Car'));
await driver.tap(find.text('Car'));
```

However, this doesn't work as I get a timeout.

Comment: When do you get timeout ? on `waitFor` or `tap` ? When dropdown is clicked upon, do you see all the values in it ?

Comment: @DK15: The menu is open and I see all the values. The timeout occurs on tap. I also tried using a key instead, but I get the same message: [warning] FlutterDriver: tap message is taking a long time to complete...

Comment: I see. I ran my test on dropdown selection and it works. What I did was -> tap on current text displayed in dropdown that shows all values -> wait for driver to find value to be selected -> tap on value to be selected, which is what you are doing. Can you try using `getText` before trying to tap on `Car` ? like `expect (driver.getText(find.text('Car')), isNotNull);`

Comment: @DK15: I just wanted to try this out when I noticed that the timeout message is actually not coming from the tap on the value, but from the tap on the DropdownButton itself! The strange thing is, that the menu is visble with all values filled.

Comment: Can you share full code of how `dropdownbutton` is implemented and related code that will be helpful to replicate the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I am also faced the same issue, But I was able to resolve issue using below code

```
       final drop = find.byValueKey('object_type');
       // First, tap the dropdown button.
       await driver.tap(drop);
       await driver.tap(find.text('Car'));
       expect(await driver.getText(find.text('Car')), isNotNull);
```

Suppose dropdown has large set of data then we need to scroll down  the dropdown and search for the expected value.

```
       final SerializableFinder dropFinder = find.byValueKey('object_type');    
       await driver.scroll(dropFinder , 0, -200, Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
       await driver.tap(find.text('Car'));
       expect(await driver.getText(find.text('Car')), isNotNull);
```